# which is efficient in terms of memory? point cloud or depth map for each view

Tags: webgl, gpu

In effect, t try to develop an application in webgl in the domain of image based rendering. my program takes as input a dense point cloud and a set of unstructured photographs from which the point cloud is estimated using teh MVS (multi view stereo). I want to know which is efficient and more economical in terms of memory (storage on graphics card) : the point cloud estimated from the set of photographs using openmvg and MVE or the depth maps corresponding to each photograph and which is estimated using MVE?

Thanks in advance:

Comment: Don't know OpenMVG or what you call a "photograph", but the answser probably lie somewhere here: A vertex needs at least 4 floats coordinates (4*32 bits), a deph map is usually 16 or 24 bits per pixel.

Comment: @Sedenion *"A vertex needs at least 4 floats coordinates (4*32 bits)"* since when?

Comment: @LJ I assume the "point cloud" is composed of 3D vertices dedicated to be transformed by a projection matrix... so, usualy float vec4...

Comment: @Sedenion To stay in "usually" land, usually nobody stores the W component since its always `1` for *3D data*, usually one'd use appropriate precision aswell, e.g. `HALF_FLOAT` could work out just fine. To add something to the (too broad / unclear) question, storing the data in the format that's easier to work with is the only sensible option here, I'd assume the processed point cloud data to be way smaller and practical than storing the individual depth maps.

Comment: @LJ you right, i just learned it is even not needed to explicitly casts vertex position to a vec4 in GLSL (we learn everyday), and yes `HALF_FLOAT` is possible type since WebGL2.